# Does SQL Server supports BNF notation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The Oracle supports Backus-Nauer Form, what about Microsoft SQL Server?

If yes, what versions are included?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot say that Oracle supports BNF. It is a notation of language. One form of representing SQL langugage is BNF. Each SQL database "supports" BNF. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the concept, sorry about that. I was reading 4.2.6 BNF Notation Conventions, in here: http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqcmd.htm and I thought that you could write in the BNF and the oracle would interpret that

Comment: But, I can't delete the post because all the answers.. :-(

Comment: @MatheusFreitas:- No need to delete the post. Just accept this as an answer if this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL Server 2005 is based on SQL-92 and **[SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql2bnf.aug92.txt)** has BNF

Comment: So, only the version 2005, or all above? and more important, do you think, or are you sure?

Comment: not very sure about all the above but for SQL 2005 it is !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
[This Link](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql2bnf.aug92.txt) file contains a depth-first tree traversal of the BNF for the  language done at about 27-AUG-1992 11:03:41.64.